# Solution to abstract linear equation system

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I want to calculate all possible solution sets of this linear equation System $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb R$:
\begin{align}
x+y+\alpha z&=\beta \\
x+\alpha y+z&=\beta \\
\alpha x+y+z&=\beta
\end{align}

Comment: You made a mistake in the last row. It should be $2-\alpha^2-\alpha$ instead of $-\alpha(\alpha-1)$.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are correct. I will edit it.

Comment: Then the rank is also not correct of course

Comment: I will assume that all your calculations are right, in that case, for $\alpha \neq 1$ and $\alpha \neq -2$, the range of the matrix is $3$ and hence invertible. That means that for any $\beta$ we have an unique solution to the system of equations.. For the cases $\alpha=1$ and $\alpha=-2$ you can write down the matrix and try to get equations for the space of solutions. If you have problem with that tell me and I will try to write a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the system you wrote $$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c} 
1 & 1 & \alpha & \beta\\
0 & \alpha-1 & 1-\alpha & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2-\alpha^2-\alpha & \beta(1-\alpha)\\
\end{array}\right]
.$$
If $\alpha=1$ the second and the third row become the zero row, so the rank of the matrix is $1$ and in this case we'll have $\infty^2$ solution.
If $\beta\ne0$ and $\alpha^2+\alpha-2=0\implies \alpha=\dfrac{-1\pm3}{2}\implies\alpha=1\text{ or }\alpha=-2$. The system has no solutions for $\alpha=2$ because we would have $0=3\beta$, with $\beta\ne 0$.For $\alpha=1$ we are in the first case that we analised.
Supposing $\alpha\ne 1,-2$ and $\beta\ne0$ you can find $z=\dfrac{(\alpha-1)\beta}{\alpha^2+\alpha-2}=\dfrac{\beta}{\alpha+2}$ and then, substituting in the second and in the first row, you find
$$(\alpha-1)y-(\alpha-1)z=0\underset{\alpha\ne1}{\implies} y=z=\dfrac{\beta}{\alpha+2}\text{ and }$$
$$x=\beta-\alpha z-y=\beta-\dfrac{\beta(\alpha+1)}{\alpha+2}\in\mathbb R.$$
If $\alpha=1$ we have
$$x=\beta-\alpha t-s,\text{ where s and t are two real free parameters}.$$
Try to think about the case in which $\beta$ is zero and $\alpha$ is $-2$ and let me know if it's now more clear for you.

Answer (score 0):

$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & \alpha  \\
 1 & \alpha  & 1 \\
 \alpha  & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
$\det A=-\alpha ^3+3 \alpha -2=-(\alpha -1)^2 (\alpha +2)$

The system has one and only one solution if $\det A\ne 0 \to \alpha\ne 1;\;\alpha\ne -2;\;\forall\beta\in\mathbb{R}$
If $\alpha=1$ then $\text{rank}(A)=1$
$$A|B=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
 1 & 1 & 1 &\beta \\
 1 & 1  & 1&\beta \\
 1  & 1 & 1&\beta \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
In order to have $\text{rank}(A|B)=1$ must be $\beta=1$

If $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=1$ the system has infinite solution which depend on two parameters.

If $\alpha=-2$ then  $\text{rank}(A)=2$
$$A|B=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
 1 & 1 & -2 &\beta \\
 1 & -2  & 1&\beta \\
 -2  & 1 & 1&\beta \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
In this case we have $\text{rank}(A|B)=2$ for any $\beta$, thus the system has infinite solutions dependent from one parameter.

TL;DR

- $\alpha\ne 1;\;\alpha\ne -2;\;\forall\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ one and only
  one solution
  $$x= \frac{\beta }{\alpha +2},y= \frac{\beta }{\alpha +2},z= \frac{\beta }{\alpha +2}$$
- $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=1$ infinite$^2$ solutions
  $$(h,k,1 - h - k);\;\forall h,k\in\mathbb{R}$$
- $\alpha=-2$ infinite solutions for any $\beta$
  $$(h,h-\beta ,h-\beta);\;\forall h\in\mathbb{R}$$